# What is the best command line argument for remote debugging of a SpringBoot app

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, java-8

I have a SpringBoot App deployed on a server which I want to connect to remotely but let it run even if I don't connect to the debug port.

baeldung (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-debugging) provides this as a mechanism to open the port

```
java -jar myapp.jar -Dagentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

This doesn't work for me (the app starts but the debug port option is ignored).  I found this online which works

```
java -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=y -jar myapp.jar
```

But it won't start the app until I actually connect from the IDE (intellij).

I'm being fussy now as this is enough really but is there a way to open the debug port let the app start up and just be available to connect to at a later point if desired ?  (Also just wondered if anyone could tell me why the baeldung option doesn't work for me, I'm assuming it's not a typo as there are no comments around it ?)

Comment: I don't really know, but I doubt it. The code as you know it might get optimized to a degree that you will not even be able to recognize, `JIT` will do that. how will you debug then? once you debug all the optimizations have to be thrown away, so that code appears exactly like you wrote it (which is never the case). a debugger is an extra-linguistic process.

Comment: Okay I guess I don't understand it enough to fully appreciate that.  My thought was that if I run it in JBOSS or 'real' Tomcat it will run and as long as I leave a port open I can attach.  I guess this is the app container making this possible then ?

Comment: Actually the answer is ,suspend=n !!!!!  Doh !  I'll delete this unless someone thinks it's useful in the next couple of days...

Comment: I wanted to post this as an answer after reading... JIT will de-optimize your method and let you debug.

Comment: I also was wondering, why i had to connect the debugger before the applications starts. suspend=n is indeed the correct answer. Maybe you should answer your own question and mark it.